# Missing linked sites in profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

I'm assuming the dev's probably know about this. At the moment, the accounts section of the profile page is saying "You have no other accounts on the Stack Exchange network" on some user pages. [My profile has no accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215013/steven-v), along with [m0sa](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156631/m0sa). But [Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140505/oded) has the other sites.

Also the profile page was brutally slow to load a few minutes ago, but the speed has returned to normal.

Comment: Caching and a network hiccup contacting the central site listing your other accounts. It'll clear itself up in due time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Aaannnddd, it's always caching. You're correct, they are showing on my profile again.

Comment: If it's consistent for one full hour then it's worth reporting, IMO.

Comment: @Oded why did you remove the norepro tag? Does it happen to you?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Nick and I saw it. Yes, it was transient, doesn't mean there isn't a problem.

Comment: @Oded oh, ghostly bug... Go ghost busters! :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - [Heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) are the best

Comment: @Oded nice, always good to learn new terms! I see Jeff also mentioned this in [his blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html). :)

Comment: It's an internal network issue we're tracking down - hang on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue with the API timing out internally was resolved shortly after - finally updating this question.