# Each site reports that I have no other accounts

Tags: bug, area-51, related-accounts

Area 51 is reporting linked accounts incorrectly. [It reports I have no other accounts on the Stack Exchange network](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/96141?tab=accounts), which is definitely not true.  Earlier today, it showed all of my accounts correctly.  I haven't changed anything about my account today.

*Edit:* I just verified that [my main SE profile page shows my accounts correctly](https://stackexchange.com/users/2348349/ed-cottrell?tab=accounts), albeit slowly.  It's incorrect on other site-specific profile pages, however, like [my SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057919/ed-cottrell).

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Seems to be working again.  Bug, or passing glitch?  Maybe a cache stampede?

Comment: This happens from time to time; the sync between the central network site profile and specific sites sometimes fails.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Makes sense. Kind of a weird, scary glitch, though. For a second I thought I'd disturbed the Force and been mass-deleted or something.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204566/missing-linked-sites-in-profiles